# Nested collection fields in Sonata Admin (2.3)

Tags: php, symfony, nested, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm having problems creating my form for creating a course. This is a part of my database scheme for which I'm trying to create a form:

[image]

So which I'm trying to do is create a course where I can create sessions and dates (moment) attached to that session. It should look something like this:

[image]

In my **CourseAdmin** class I have:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('name',                   'text',         array('label' => 'Naam'))
        ->add('description',            'textarea',     array('label' => 'Beschrijving'))
        ->add('materials',              'textarea',     array('label' => 'Benodigde materialen'))
        ->add('numberOfParticipants',   'number',       array('label' => 'Aantal deelnembers'))
        ->add('numberOfDays',           'number',       array('label' => 'Aantal dagen'))
        ->add('price',                  'number',       array('label' => 'Prijs'))
        ->add('priceKmo',               'number',       array('label' => 'KMO-portefeuille Prijs'))

        ->add('location', 'sonata_type_model', array('expanded' => true, 'by_reference' => false, 'multiple' => true, 'btn_add' => false))

        ->add('session', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
            'by_reference' => false,
            'type_options' => array(
                // Prevents the "Delete" option from being displayed
                'delete' => false,
                'delete_options' => array(
                    // You may otherwise choose to put the field but hide it
                    'type'         => 'hidden',
                    // In that case, you need to fill in the options as well
                    'type_options' => array(
                        'mapped'   => false,
                        'required' => false,
                    )
                )
            )
        ), array(
            'edit' => 'inline',
            'inline' => 'table',
            'sortable' => 'position'
        ))
    ;
}
```

In my **SessionAdmin** class I have:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('type',      'text',     array('label' => 'Type opleiding (Dag / Avond)'))
        ->add('moment', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
            'by_reference' => false,
            'type_options' => array(
                // Prevents the "Delete" option from being displayed
                'delete' => false,
                'delete_options' => array(
                    // You may otherwise choose to put the field but hide it
                    'type'         => 'hidden',
                    // In that case, you need to fill in the options as well
                    'type_options' => array(
                        'mapped'   => false,
                        'required' => false,
                    )
                )
            )
        ), array(
            'edit' => 'inline',
            'inline' => 'table',
            'sortable' => 'position'
        ))
        ;
}
```

And in my **MomentAdmin** class I have:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('time',      'date',     array('label' => 'Datum'))
    ;
}
```

The problem in my form is when I try to add a moment (date) to my session I get the following error:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getName() on null in /myproject/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 9772

So, I can add a session but when I try to add a moment to my session I'm getting the error ... .

When I look in the file **classes.php** on rule 9771 and 9772 there is:

```
$childFormBuilder = $this->getChildFormBuilder($formBuilder, $elementId);
$fieldDescription = $admin->getFormFieldDescription($childFormBuilder->getName());
```

The `$childFormBuilder` is **null**.

When I look at that function than I get this:

```
public function getChildFormBuilder(FormBuilder $formBuilder, $elementId)
{
    foreach (new FormBuilderIterator($formBuilder) as $name => $formBuilder) {
        if ($name == $elementId) {
            return $formBuilder;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

When I do a var_dump of $name and $elementId like this:

```
public function getChildFormBuilder(FormBuilder $formBuilder, $elementId)
{
    foreach (new FormBuilderIterator($formBuilder) as $name => $formBuilder) {
        var_dump("name: " . $name);
        var_dump("elementId: " . $elementId);

        if ($name == $elementId) {
            return $formBuilder;
        }
    } 
    die;
    return;
}
```

And push on the Add new button like the following picture:

[image]

Then I get this output:

```
name: s56cda71d2daa0_name
elementId: s56cda71d2daa0_session_0_moment

name: s56cda71d2daa0_description
elementId: s56cda71d2daa0_session_0_moment

name: s56cda71d2daa0_materials
elementId: s56cda71d2daa0_session_0_moment

name: s56cda71d2daa0_numberOfParticipants
elementId: s56cda71d2daa0_session_0_moment

name: s56cda71d2daa0_numberOfDays
elementId: s56cda71d2daa0_session_0_moment

name: s56cda71d2daa0_price
elementId: s56cda71d2daa0_session_0_moment

name: s56cda71d2daa0_priceKmo
elementId: s56cda71d2daa0_session_0_moment

name: s56cda71d2daa0_location
elementId: s56cda71d2daa0_session_0_moment

name: s56cda71d2daa0_session
elementId: s56cda71d2daa0_session_0_moment
```

In all my entities I have a __toString function. An example in my Course entity:

```
public function __toString()
{
    if(!is_null($this->name))
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

What could be the problem here? I'm really stuck with this. I've also posted an [issue](http://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/3583) on the github repo of Sonata Admin but no answers ...

***My entities***:

**Course Entity**:

```
<?php

namespace Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Course
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="course")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Course
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="materials", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $materials;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="number_of_participants", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $numberOfParticipants;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="number_of_days", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $numberOfDays;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="decimal", nullable=true)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price_kmo", type="decimal", nullable=true)
     */
    private $priceKmo;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Location", inversedBy="course")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="course_has_location",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="location_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $location;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Session", mappedBy="course")
     */
    private $session;

    /**
     * Add session
     *
     * @param \Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Session $session
     * @return Session
     */
    public function addSession(\Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Session $session)
    {
        $this->session[] = $session;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove session
     *
     * @param \Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Session $session
     */
    public function removeSession(\Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Session $session)
    {
        $this->session->removeElement($session);
    }

    /**
     * Get session
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getSession()
    {
        return $this->session;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->location = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        if(!is_null($this->name))
        {
            return $this->name;
        }
        else{
            return "";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Course
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Course
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set materials
     *
     * @param string $materials
     * @return Course
     */
    public function setMaterials($materials)
    {
        $this->materials = $materials;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get materials
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getMaterials()
    {
        return $this->materials;
    }

    /**
     * Set numberOfParticipants
     *
     * @param integer $numberOfParticipants
     * @return Course
     */
    public function setNumberOfParticipants($numberOfParticipants)
    {
        $this->numberOfParticipants = $numberOfParticipants;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get numberOfParticipants
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getNumberOfParticipants()
    {
        return $this->numberOfParticipants;
    }

    /**
     * Set numberOfDays
     *
     * @param integer $numberOfDays
     * @return Course
     */
    public function setNumberOfDays($numberOfDays)
    {
        $this->numberOfDays = $numberOfDays;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get numberOfDays
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getNumberOfDays()
    {
        return $this->numberOfDays;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param string $price
     * @return Course
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * Set priceKmo
     *
     * @param string $priceKmo
     * @return Course
     */
    public function setPriceKmo($priceKmo)
    {
        $this->priceKmo = $priceKmo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get priceKmo
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPriceKmo()
    {
        return $this->priceKmo;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add location
     *
     * @param \Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Location $location
     * @return Course
     */
    public function addLocation(\Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Location $location)
    {
        $this->location[] = $location;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove location
     *
     * @param \Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Location $location
     */
    public function removeLocation(\Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Location $location)
    {
        $this->location->removeElement($location);
    }

    /**
     * Get location
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $this->location;
    }
}
```

**Session Entity**:

```
    <?php

namespace Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Session
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="session")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Session
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Course
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Course", inversedBy="session")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
     * })
     */
    private $course;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Moment", mappedBy="session")
     */
    private $moment;

    /**
     * Add moment
     *
     * @param \Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Moment $moment
     * @return Moment
     */
    public function addMoment(\Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Moment $moment)
    {
        $this->moment[] = $moment;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove moment
     *
     * @param \Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Moment $moment
     */
    public function removeMoment(\Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Moment $moment)
    {
        $this->moment->removeElement($moment);
    }

    /**
     * Get moment
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getMoment()
    {
        return $this->moment;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        if(!is_null($this->type))
        {
            return $this->type;
        }
        else{
            return "";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @return Session
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set course
     *
     * @param \Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Course $course
     * @return Session
     */
    public function setCourse(\Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Course $course = null)
    {
        $this->course = $course;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get course
     *
     * @return \Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Course 
     */
    public function getCourse()
    {
        return $this->course;
    }
}
```

**Moment Entity**:

```
<?php

namespace Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Moment
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="moment")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Moment
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="time", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $time;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Session
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Session")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="session_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
     * })
     */
    private $session;

    public function __toString()
    {
        if(!is_null($this->time))
        {
            return $this->time;
        }
        else{
            return "";
        }
    }



    /**
     * Set time
     *
     * @param \DateTime $time
     * @return Moment
     */
    public function setTime($time)
    {
        $this->time = $time;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get time
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getTime()
    {
        return $this->time;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set session
     *
     * @param \Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Session $session
     * @return Moment
     */
    public function setSession(\Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Session $session = null)
    {
        $this->session = $session;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get session
     *
     * @return \Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Session 
     */
    public function getSession()
    {
        return $this->session;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've added some var_dumps to my function **getChildFormBuilder** like this:

```
public function getChildFormBuilder(FormBuilder $formBuilder, $elementId)
{
    foreach (new FormBuilderIterator($formBuilder) as $name => $formBuilder) {
        if ($name == $elementId) {
            return $formBuilder;
        }
    }

    var_dump(__METHOD__);
    var_dump($elementId);
    var_dump(debug_backtrace());

    return;
}
```

The result is this:

```
string 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminHelper::getChildFormBuilder' (length=57)
string 's56cdfa72c4dea_session_0_moment' (length=31)
array (size=8)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'file' => string '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/studyx_enrolments/app/cache/dev/classes.php' (length=69)
      'line' => int 9774
      'function' => string 'getChildFormBuilder' (length=19)
      'class' => string 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminHelper' (length=36)
      'object' => 
        object(Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminHelper)[339]
          protected 'pool' => 
            object(Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Pool)[104]
              ...
      'type' => string '->' (length=2)
      'args' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder)[436]
              ...
          1 => &string 's56cdfa72c4dea_session_0_moment' (length=31)
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      'file' => string '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/studyx_enrolments/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Controller/HelperController.php' (length=110)
      'line' => int 95
      'function' => string 'appendFormFieldElement' (length=22)
      'class' => string 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminHelper' (length=36)
      'object' => 
        object(Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminHelper)[339]
          protected 'pool' => 
            object(Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Pool)[104]
              ...
      'type' => string '->' (length=2)
      'args' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            object(Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Admin\CourseAdmin)[370]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(Studyx\EnrolmentBundle\Entity\Course)[415]
              ...
          2 => &string 's56cdfa72c4dea_session_0_moment' (length=31)
  2 => 
    array (size=5)
      'function' => string 'appendFormFieldElementAction' (length=28)
      'class' => string 'Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\HelperController' (length=46)
      'object' => 
        object(Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\HelperController)[244]
          protected 'twig' => 
            object(Twig_Environment)[220]
              ...
          protected 'helper' => 
            object(Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminHelper)[339]
              ...
          protected 'pool' => 
            object(Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Pool)[104]
              ...
          protected 'validator' => 
            object(Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator)[340]
              ...
      'type' => string '->' (length=2)
      'args' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)[6]
              ...
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      'file' => string '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/studyx_enrolments/app/bootstrap.php.cache' (length=67)
      'line' => int 2957
      'function' => string 'call_user_func_array' (length=20)
      'args' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => &
            array (size=2)
              ...
          1 => &
            array (size=1)
              ...
  4 => 
    array (size=7)
      'file' => string '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/studyx_enrolments/app/bootstrap.php.cache' (length=67)
      'line' => int 2931
      'function' => string 'handleRaw' (length=9)
      'class' => string 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel' (length=39)
      'object' => 
        object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel)[300]
          protected 'container' => 
            object(appDevDebugProjectContainer)[304]
              ...
          protected 'dispatcher' => 
            object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher)[299]
              ...
          protected 'resolver' => 
            object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\TraceableControllerResolver)[249]
              ...
      'type' => string '->' (length=2)
      'args' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)[6]
              ...
          1 => &int 1
  5 => 
    array (size=7)
      'file' => string '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/studyx_enrolments/app/bootstrap.php.cache' (length=67)
      'line' => int 3060
      'function' => string 'handle' (length=6)
      'class' => string 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel' (length=39)
      'object' => 
        object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel)[300]
          protected 'container' => 
            object(appDevDebugProjectContainer)[304]
              ...
          protected 'dispatcher' => 
            object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher)[299]
              ...
          protected 'resolver' => 
            object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\TraceableControllerResolver)[249]
              ...
      'type' => string '->' (length=2)
      'args' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)[6]
              ...
          1 => &int 1
          2 => &boolean true
  6 => 
    array (size=7)
      'file' => string '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/studyx_enrolments/app/bootstrap.php.cache' (length=67)
      'line' => int 2333
      'function' => string 'handle' (length=6)
      'class' => string 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel' (length=73)
      'object' => 
        object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel)[300]
          protected 'container' => 
            object(appDevDebugProjectContainer)[304]
              ...
          protected 'dispatcher' => 
            object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher)[299]
              ...
          protected 'resolver' => 
            object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\TraceableControllerResolver)[249]
              ...
      'type' => string '->' (length=2)
      'args' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)[6]
              ...
          1 => &int 1
          2 => &boolean true
  7 => 
    array (size=7)
      'file' => string '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/studyx_enrolments/web/app_dev.php' (length=59)
      'line' => int 29
      'function' => string 'handle' (length=6)
      'class' => string 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel' (length=35)
      'object' => 
        object(AppKernel)[5]
          protected 'bundles' => 
            array (size=22)
              ...
          protected 'bundleMap' => 
            array (size=22)
              ...
          protected 'container' => 
            object(appDevDebugProjectContainer)[304]
              ...
          protected 'rootDir' => string '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/studyx_enrolments/app' (length=47)
          protected 'environment' => string 'dev' (length=3)
          protected 'debug' => boolean true
          protected 'booted' => boolean true
          protected 'name' => string 'app' (length=3)
          protected 'startTime' => float 1456339594.61
          protected 'loadClassCache' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      'type' => string '->' (length=2)
      'args' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)[6]
              ...
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I've changed the require in my composer.json to "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^2.4@dev" and updated with composer. But now I'm getting this error:

> ContextErrorException: Warning: Illegal string offset 'admin' in
>   app/cache/dev/classes.php line 10482

The error is in this function:

```
public function getDashboardGroups()
{
    $groups = $this->adminGroups;
    foreach ($this->adminGroups as $name => $adminGroup) {
        if (isset($adminGroup['items'])) {
            foreach ($adminGroup['items'] as $key => $item) {
                if (''!= $item['admin']) {
                    $admin = $this->getInstance($item['admin']);
                    if ($admin->showIn(Admin::CONTEXT_DASHBOARD)) {
                        $groups[$name]['items'][$key] = $admin;
                    } else {
                        unset($groups[$name]['items'][$key]);
                    }
                } 
                else {
                    unset($groups[$name]['items'][$key]);
                }
            }
        }
        if (empty($groups[$name]['items'])) {
            unset($groups[$name]);
        }
    }
    return $groups;
}
```

The errors in on line : `if (''!= $item['admin']) {` .

In my **config.yml** I have:

```
sonata_admin:
title:      Studyx
title_logo: bundles/studyxenrolment/images/logo.png
templates:
    layout:                 StudyxEnrolmentBundle:Admin:standard_layout.html.twig
    edit:                   StudyxEnrolmentBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig
    user_block:             StudyxEnrolmentBundle:Admin:user_block.html.twig
#        search:                 SonataAdminBundle:Core:search.html.twig
#        search_result_block:    SonataAdminBundle:Block:block_search_result.html.twig
dashboard:
    groups:
        studyx.admin.group.inschrijvingen:
            label: Inschrijvingen
            items: ~
            item_adds:
                - sonata.admin.enrolment

        studyx.admin.group.algemeen:
            label: Algemeen
            items: ~
            item_adds:
                - sonata.admin.course
                - sonata.admin.student

        studyx.admin.group.extra:
            label: Extra
            items: ~
            item_adds:
                - sonata.admin.location
    blocks:
        -
            position: top
            class: col-md-12
            type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list
```

So I think the function **getDashboardGroups** is called there.

**UPDATE 3:**

In my **composer.json** I have now the following:

```
"sonata-project/block-bundle": "~2.3",
"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^2.4@dev",
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.3.*",
"sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "^2.3"
```

Should I update them all to `^2.4@dev` ?

Comment: give us the block code that it's responsible for this FatalErrorException (line 9772...)

Comment: Apparently your `$this->getChildFormBuilder($formBuilder, $elementId);` method doesn't return a formBuilder, but `null` instead. Can you share that code?

Comment: I don't see anything weird at this point, so I would start by just adding some `var_dumps`  in the getChildFormBuilder, to check the `$elementId` and the `$name` variables, and see if they actually match.

Comment: @NicoKaag, the problem is they don't match .. But I don't know the reason why they don't match ...

Comment: nielsv I see that you've accepted chalasr's answer, does that mean that you were are to solve the problem ? If yes what ended up working for you ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error occurs because you have more than two level of nested collection forms, and it's currently not yet supported in any release of sonata-admin.

From [@rande](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/262#issuecomment-2773237) (owner) and sonata maintainers at issues [#262](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/262), [#1228](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/1228), [#1327](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/1327) and [#1971](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/1971) :

> This is still not supported for now ....

You can also look at this old PR [#1971](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/1971) which should solve the problem for some use cases only.

The solution I propose you is to implement the fix provided by the last opened PR [#2985](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/2985/commits).
Because the PR is not merged, you need to tell composer to load it  rather than the current (not-working as expected) version. (see [composer and VCS](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository)).

Hope the PR is merged soon.
Until it is, feel free to fix your problem at the moment by using it directly, as several people do.

**UPDATE**

The [Pull Request #3553](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/3553) has been recently merged and fix the problem of the nested collections at > 2 levels (nested in nested).

To get the fixed release, you must use the `dev-master` tag of the bundle (at least from the [commit 926f159](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/commit/926f15924f612c75366472d99bedf8c6ca25ea68) representing the merge of the PR).

I tried it and it works well with the following requirement:

```
// composer.json

"require": {
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^2.4@dev",
     ...
},
```

I hope you can easily upgrade the bundle in order to get the fix.

**Update2**

Apparently, your composer doesn't take the last changes of the branch.
The fix provided by the PR [#2739](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/2739) has been merged 6 days ago.

To fix this last one (hope), you need to change a very short code block in the `AddDepencyCallsCompilerPass` located in `vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/AddDependencyCallsCompilerPass`.

At line 95, replace this line :

```
$groupDefaults[$resolvedGroupName]['items'][] = $id;
```

To those ones:

```
$groupDefaults[$resolvedGroupName]['items'][] = array(
    'admin'        => $id,
    'label'        => !empty($attributes['label']) ? $attributes['label'] : '',
    'route'        => '',
    'route_params' => array(),
);
```

Like it's done by the PR (it's the only needed change to make it working).

I would make the fix manually because it's very new, and after some days/weeks, run the following commands:

`composer clear-cache` and `composer update sonata-project/admin-bundle`

You should try it now before adding the fix manually, maybe the changes will be added.

Also, you can use the link about composer and VCS I given at the begin of my answer and require the fix directly. It's at your own appreciation because of it's a solution at the moment.

And last, be patient, the fixes will be merged in stable releases soon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated with composer but now I'm getting another error. I've updated my topic (UPDATE 2). Could you take a look?

Comment: Can you say me where is the method `getDashboardGroups` and how/where do you call it ?

Comment: I updated my answer with a fix. Don't forget to clear the cache manually by removing all inside the cache directory.

Comment: I've updated my topic one last time, just a little question. Could you take a look?

Comment: Yes you should, sonata bundles are related, you may have problems with different version. Use the same for at least admin-bundle, user-bundle, doctrine-orm-admin-bundle & block-bundle. I work with them together on 2.4@dev without any problemw

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getChildFormBuilder(FormBuilder $formBuilder, $elementId)
{
    foreach (new FormBuilderIterator($formBuilder) as $name => $formBuilder) {
        if ($name == $elementId) {
            return $formBuilder;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Dumping the name and element id within the loop won't accomplish anything. Your application obviously crashes when there is nothing to iterate - it then walks through the loop, exits and goes to the last line where `NULL` is returned.

I suggest you dump the element id just after the loop, like the following. The use of [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) might also help:

```
public function getChildFormBuilder(FormBuilder $formBuilder, $elementId)
{
    foreach (new FormBuilderIterator($formBuilder) as $name => $formBuilder) {
        if ($name == $elementId) {
            return $formBuilder;
        }
    }

var_dump(__METHOD__);
var_dump($elementId);
var_dump(debug_backtrace());

    return;
}
```